# uwsgi web app with cron tasks?

Tags: python, cron, uwsgi, web.py, apscheduler

I wrote an app using webpy (webpy.org). Part of this web app is recurring background tasks for statistical functions. I used `APScheduler` python library to perform cron style schedules. Because `app.run()` let webpy run in standalone mode during development. This setup worked out fine.

However, when it's deployed, I discovered that APScheduler no longer functions. Deployment procedure pretty much follows [this article](http://fartersoft.com/blog/2012/02/10/deployment-of-web-py-applications-using-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu/). My entry point program still prints successful scheduling logs. But it appears that uwsgi will suspend the running webpy app (making the thread suspended) when no requests are received. If I refresh a page, APScheduler will wakeup, printing a few `WARNING:apscheduler.scheduler:Run time of job "worker (trigger: cron[...], next run at: ..)" was missed by 0:04:36.389705` messages. They are not running according to the schedule.

My question is, how do I schedule cron style tasks when deploying a uwsgi webpy app. I saw uwsgi itself has cron support. But I wonder how I can mix it with my app, like APScheduler (or replace it)? The tasks depends on a few modules and dynamic properties of the app, so they can't be easily converted into standalone .py programs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the ApsScheduler requires threads, you should enable them with --enable-threads in uWSGI